# Image alignment in fancyhdr footer

Tags: fancyhdr

folks!

I'm aiming to have an image in the center of the footer, but I'm not being able to make it work, the image is sticking out, the content of the footer is not getting top aligned.

I'm using [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr) to build this footer.

Bellow there is an image showing what I'm facing and the full code.

[image: image shows wrong footer alignment]

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for Lorem ipsum text
\usepackage{lastpage}

\geometry{a4paper,
  top=0.75in,
  bottom=1.5in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  headheight=14.5pt, % the default is too short
  heightrounded, % avoids the need of a flexible baselineskip
} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyhead[R]{}%
  \fancyfoot{}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% ==== FOOTER ======

\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize
Jane Doe\\
123456789\\
jane.doe@gmail.com
}

\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize
    Page \thepage  \textbackslash \pageref*{LastPage}
}

\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[height=50pt]{ymcalogo}}

% \fancyfoot[C]{Foo Bar}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Had the same idea as the answer below. // Is the alignment of address and page number ok?

Comment: Yeah, it seems ok if I remove the center content of the footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox` to move the baseline of the image to match the baseline of  the text.  `\ht\strutbox` is the distance from the top of a `\strut` to the baseline (which depends on the font size).  You can also use `valign=t` from adjustbox [export].

The footer does not have an equivalent to `\headheight`, since `\footskip` is the distance from the text area to the baseline of the footer, not to the bottom.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for Lorem ipsum text
\usepackage{lastpage}

\geometry{a4paper,
  top=0.75in,
  bottom=1.5in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  headheight=14.5pt, % size of image
  heightrounded, % avoids the need of a flexible baselineskip
} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyhead[R]{}%
  \fancyfoot{}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% ==== FOOTER ======

\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize
Jane Doe\\
123456789\\
jane.doe@gmail.com
}

\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize
    Page \thepage  \textbackslash \pageref*{LastPage}
}

\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{\includegraphics[height=50pt]{example-image}}}

% \fancyfoot[C]{Foo Bar}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Boom! It works just like magic. I didn't know the raisebox command. Actually, a lot of knew commands in your answer that I'll search the documentation.